How to properly send an array of objects to the backend using fetch?
I have an array of objects of company hierarchy that I need to send to the backend:
selectedTeams: [
  0: {team: "some_team_1", division: "some_division_1"}
  1: {team: "some_team_2", division: "some_division_2"}
  2: {team: "some_team_3", division: "some_division_3"}
]

I am trying to do the following using URLSearchParams:
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlParams.append('selected_teams', selectedTeams)
fetch(`${backendUrl}?` + urlParams)
  .then(..)

But it is null because it's clearly not correct.
What is the proper way to do that? I can change the data types if needed (for example change it from array of objects to object of objects etc..)

Please console.log the full urlParams URL. console.log("/backend-url" + urlParams) likely prints /backend-urlselected_teams=... etc. - notice the ? is missing. I assume this is just a typo.

yes thank you, it's just a typo, I do have the ?, fixed the post

Okay sure, I retracted the close vote. Do you have access to the logs for this backend? It doesn't return any validation error? There is no universal way to transfer complex data types. You have to check the backend's code, logs or API docs.

Have you tried JSON.stringify(selectedTeams)? Usually URL params expect a string. You can also send it as part of the request body. You should check the things that @PeterPointer said

"But it is null" what is null? Where are you seeing the null? Note that the code you posted is not syntactically valid JS....

You can not add just any arbitrary data type using append. URL parameters are text, so whatever you pass, will be converted into a string value. Passing an object, will only get you the literal text [object Object] appended as the value of your parameter. You will need to serialize this into a text format in some way - for example by encoding it as JSON.

Thanks everyone, I was wrong and actually had a mistake in the backend (tried to access the wrong input name) and that's why I got null. When I fixed that indeed I got [Object object] which I then fixed using JSON.stringify()

Passing selectedTeams to append will result in [object Object], not the data you wish.
If you want to just send the objects, stringify them:
urlParams.append('selected_teams', selectedTeams.map(JSON.stringify))



const selectedTeams = [
  {team: "some_team_1", division: "some_division_1"},
  {team: "some_team_2", division: "some_division_2"},
  {team: "some_team_3", division: "some_division_3"}
]

const urlParams = new URLSearchParams();
urlParams.append('selected_teams', selectedTeams.map(JSON.stringify))

console.log('?' + urlParams)



